How Can We Improve Human-Robot Collaboration in Dynamic Environments Using Real-Time Adaptation?
How Can We Improve Human-Robot Collaboration in Dynamic Environments Using Real-Time Adaptation?
I've been working on a robotics project where we aim to have robots collaborate closely with humans in dynamic environments, like factories or even public spaces. While the robots perform well in controlled settings, they struggle to adapt in real-time when the environment changes rapidly, such as when humans move unpredictably or new obstacles appear.
I'm curious about the state-of-the-art techniques or algorithms that can be employed to improve this real-time adaptation. Specifically, how can robots better predict human movement or environmental changes to maintain seamless collaboration? Are there any successful implementations of machine learning models, sensor fusion techniques, or real-time path planning that significantly enhance human-robot interaction in such scenarios?
Any insights, relevant research papers, or experiences with similar challenges would be greatly appreciated!
